# How to fix ping pong with lora working only on RX_timeout and TX_timeout in stm32 in C language

Tags: c, stm32

I'm working with the ping pong with lora in stm32 , the code doesn't recieve anything , it only executes the RX_timeout and TX_timeout while the device in the other side is sending DATA correctly with lora,
How can I fix this problem  ?

this is in the stm32 : B-l072Z-LRWAN1 with I-CUBE-LRWAN firmware package

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

What keys are you using? And is your gateway in range and working correctly? Are you receiving uplinks from the node?

Comment: Probably the radio modules aren't configured the same way. This is way too broad a question.

Comment: I'm using the ping pong code on B-l072Z-LRWAN1 with I-CUBE-LRWAN firmware package and a device sending data  with CMWX1ZZABZ-091 open module by Murata
I tested the device on the gateway and it's sending correctly , but there is no reception in the code of ping pong (while rx and tx parameters are the same like the device code)  .

Comment: the radio module is configured the same way

Comment: Acctually ,It was a problem with the stm board , the jumpers must be in their default position